# Proof of existence in division with remainder

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

************************Proposition.************************ Let $a\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $b\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then there exist unique numbers $q,r\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $b=qa+r; 0≤r<a.$

*******Proof.*******

Existence:

Define $S:=\{b-qa \mid q\in \mathbb{Z}, b-qa\in \mathbb{N}\}$. We show that $S$ is non-empty as follows:

- If $b≥0$, choose $q=0$,
- If $b<0$, choose $q=b$.

Then by the least integer principle, $S$ has a minimal element. Call it $r$. Thus $b=qa+r$, where $r≥0$, since $r\in\mathbb{N}$. Also, we have $r<a$ as otherwise $b-(q+1)a=r-a\in\mathbb{N}$, which contradicts the minimality of $r$.

---

How is the contradiction in the r≥a case established? I don't see how they even used the hypothesis $r≥a$ Wouldn't we require b-(q+1)a ≥ 0?
since otherwise, it won't even be an element of S

Comment: Both $r-a$ and $r$ are in $S$ and $0\le r-a<r$ would contradicts $r$ minimality. So $r<a$ is the true.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! The change in perspective with the lower bounding of r-a really helps

Comment: u r welcome ! .

Comment: Please delete the question once all is clear as this is a duplicate many times over.